# Concate two String of Diffrent font size

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

```
<h:outputText value="#{myWalletBean.homeMessage}"></h:outputText>
<h4>
    <h:outputText value="#{myWalletBean.walletMoney}">
        <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="Rs."/>
    </h:outputText>
</h4>
```

this gives me output in two different line,but i want output in a single line such as "Wallet amount Rs.100".

Comment: Have you tried? display:inline-block or float

Comment: No i didn't,can you pass any link where i can find syntax for it

Answer (score 0):

You can try it. I hope that helps.

```
<h:outputText value="Wallet amount&#160;"></h:outputText> 
  <h:outputText styleClass="h4" value="#{33333.33}">  
   <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="Rs."/>
</h:outputText>
```

`&#160;` for whitespace.

```
.h4 { 
/*     display: block; */
    margin-top: 1.33em;
    margin-bottom: 1.33em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

> Most browsers will display the  element with the following default values:

See also [Default CSS Settings](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp)

---

Looks like this.

[image]